# Tokenize sentence into words, considering special characters

Tags: c++, string, special-characters, tokenize

I have a function that receive a sentence, and tokenize into words, based on space " ". 
Now, I want to improve the function to eliminate some special characters, for example:

```
I am a boy.   => {I, am, a, boy}, no period after "boy"
I said :"are you ok?"  => {I, said, are, you, ok}, no question and quotation mark
```

The original function is here, how can I improve it?

```
void Tokenize(const string& str, vector<string>& tokens, const string& delimiters = " ")
{

    string::size_type lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, 0);

    string::size_type pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);

    while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos)
    {

        tokens.push_back(str.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));

        lastPos = str.find_first_not_of(delimiters, pos);

        pos = str.find_first_of(delimiters, lastPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: copy str into a str2while removing special characters. Do all the operations you're doing on str2

Comment: If you want to improve the function, you first need to define what *you* consider better. Then, I'd suggest you write tests, both for the already working cases and for the cases where it doesn't work as good as you want it to. Then, try to improve the function and if you have any specific problems with that, ask here. As it stands, it looks like you are only looking for someone here to write it for you.

Comment: For all string manipulation I would advice boost spirit to get rid of manual manipulation, index calculation... But it's some kind of sledgehammer and difficult to learn [link] http://boost-spirit.com/home/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `std::regex`. There you could search, whatever you want and then put the result in a vector. That is rather simple.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

// Our test data (raw string). So, containing also \" and so on
std::string testData(R"#(I said :"are you ok?")#");

std::regex re(R"#((\b\w+\b,?))#");

int main(void)
{
    // Define the variable id as vector of string and use the range constructor to read the test data and tokenize it
    std::vector<std::string> id{ std::sregex_token_iterator(testData.begin(), testData.end(), re, 1), std::sregex_token_iterator() };

    // For debug output. Print complete vector to std::cout
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));

    return 0;
}
```